# openssl error when getting servers from amazon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fog

i have been using this since last 2 weeks, but today i got one error like
***hostname "ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)***

```
@aws_credentials = {
:provider => "AWS",
:aws_access_key_id => access_key_id,
:aws_secret_access_key => secret_access_key
}
line 1: conn2 = Fog::Compute.new(@aws_credentials.merge(:region => 'sa-east-1'))
line 2: conn2.servers.all.each do |server|
end
```

so i got that error in line 1, actually i don’t have server in this 'sa-east-1' region. but if give the region, which i have the server, it will not give any errors.

Comment: that’s working now, when i have use this

Excon.ssl_verify_peer = false, is there any issue with that?

Comment: We discussed and resolved this on the github issue here: https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/2876